# system.data.function' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I'm getting error at this point 'Function' saying that system.data.function' is inaccessible due to its protection level when i tried to convert it from vb.net to c#

```
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(Function, x, x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(Function, x, x).FirstOrDefault.ToString();
```

below is my code, Thanks for the help.

```
        System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream networkStream = default(System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream);
        //-> some way it is called initialization or getting stream from the connected port.

        networkStream = HL7Server.GetStream();

        //-->check we have data
        //GetACK(networkStream, True)

        //-> write to net stream

        networkStream.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length);

        networkStream.Flush();


        //HL7Server.Close()
        hasConnected = false;

        //-> get current MSH segment 
        dynamic mSplittxt = hl7message.Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(11).ToString(), "").Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(28).ToString(), "").Split(System.Convert.ToChar(13));
        //mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault.ToString();
        mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(Function, x, x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(Function, x, x).FirstOrDefault.ToString();


        //MessageBox.Show("BEFORE ACK MSH: " & mMSH)

        //-> get acknowledgment.

        bool hasData = false;
        int retStat = 0;
        System.DateTime stTim = System.DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan sp = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(stTim);
        // wait for 5 seconds to get ack
        while (true)
        {
            hasData = GetACK(ref networkStream, false, ref retStat);
            sp = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(stTim);
            // stay until 5 seconds or success acknowledge received
            if (sp.Seconds > 5 | hasData == true)
                break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That lambda syntax is incorrect for c#

```
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|"))
                .Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

It can probably be corrected so that you don't end up calling `ToString` if it is null.

```
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|"))
                .Select(x => x.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

or even

```
mMSH = mSplittxt.Select(x => x.ToString())
                .Where(x => x.StartsWith("MSH|"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you translate vb to c#, but the usual `.Where()` syntax is as follows:

```
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|"))
                .Select(x => x)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .ToString();
```

Please note, that I've also corrected the `Select` statement, as well as `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, generally this VB.NET lambda syntax :

```
Function(x) x
```

can be converted to C# syntax as :

```
x => x
```

So example for your case is as follow :

```
//VB.NET version
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(Function(x) x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(Function(x) x).FirstOrDefault().ToString()

//C# version
mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All for your quick response. i got it solved.

String[] mSplittxt = hl7message.Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(11).ToString(), "").Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(28).ToString(), "").Split(System.Convert.ToChar(13));

mMSH = mSplittxt.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|")).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();